# Event handling on save button click

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I need to simply check if entered data in maintenance view, which is called via 'call transaction' fits under certain criteria. But the main requirement - is to perform this check when user clicks on save button. Is such handling even possible or at least sane?

Comment: Please describe a) the criteria, b) the action that is supposed to happen if the data doesn't match and c) the exact reason why the maintenance view is called via `CALL TRANSACTION` (if there is one besides "I don't know how to do it otherwise")

Comment: Criteria - is just to check if the entered info is exist in other table, its called this way because there's a trigger in main program - if one condition - it opens ALV, if another - it should transmit data into this transaction, and later it should check - if entered data is valid. If something wrong - it should pop up error message.

Answer (score 1):

1. To check whether the data exists in another table, define a foreign key relationship between the tables. This will make the generated view maintenance program automatically check the validity - no need to code anything.
2. To call the view maintenance, use the function module `VIEW_MAINTENANCE_CALL` (and read its documentation). This will give you a much more fine-grained control over the application.

Comment: Thanks. The VIEW_MAINTENANCE_CALL - was just right thing.